# Iterate through codepoints: String.codePointAt vs BreakIterator vs IntStream

Tags: java, android, string, unicode

I can iterate through the codepoints of a string using either of the following two ways:

[*String.codePointAt*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527891/3681880)

```
final int length = s.length();
for (int offset = 0; offset < length; ) {
   final int codepoint = s.codePointAt(offset);

   // do something with the codepoint

   offset += Character.charCount(codepoint);
}
```

[*BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42219474/3681880)

```
BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance();
boundary.setText(s);
int start = boundary.first();
for (int end = boundary.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; end = boundary.next()) {
    int codepoint = text.substring(start, end);

    // do something with the codepoint

    start = end;
}
```

From a performance perspective, is one any better than the other? I need to iterate through codepoints in a custom view and performance is a factor.

**Update**

As was noted in the comments, it would be good to include `CharSequence.codePoints()`, which is an `IntStream`. However, I am struggling to understand how streams work. Currently I have read [this](http://www.deadcoderising.com/2015-05-19-java-8-replace-traditional-for-loops-with-intstreams/), [this](http://www.deadcoderising.com/java-8-no-more-loops/), and [this](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/java-util-stream-intstream-example/). This probably deserves a new question.

I am also adding the Android tag, since I am doing this in Android and [`IntStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) was not added until API 24.

Comment: Starting from Java 8 there is [another way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) that uses Streams, maybe add that one too?

Comment: @ToddSewell, That's a new one to me. Thanks for letting me know.